# How to deny acces for other users in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following function in my Controller:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/incomes/show/{id}", name="incomes_show")
     */
    public function listIncomesAction($id)
    {
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($id);

        $userIncomes = $user->getIncomes();

        return $this->render('incomes/show.user.incomes.html.twig', array(
            'incomes' => $userIncomes
        ));
    }
}
```

It is working perfectly, but i want to denied acces for other users i. e only the current logged in user have access to his list of incomes. Now when i change the id in the URL, it opens the other users incomes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try like this ?

```
/**
 * @Route("/incomes/show", name="incomes_show")
 */
public function listIncomesAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $userIncomes = $user->getIncomes();

    return $this->render('incomes/show.user.incomes.html.twig', array(
        'incomes' => $userIncomes
    ));
}
```